# Tainted canvases may not be exported in android

Tags: javascript, android, canvas, video, cross-origin-embedder-policy

I'm trying to use canvas to take a screenshot in the video(m3u8) that is playing and I get the following error, Error only on Android, ios and desktop web are ok.

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.

this is my code

```js
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = this.videoEl.videoWidth; // this.videoEl is video element
canvas.height = this.videoEl.videoHeight;
canvas.getContext('2d')?.drawImage(this.videoEl, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);
return imgData;
```

And I set crossOrigin = 'Anonymous' on video Element

What should I do?

Comment: Load the images/videos from your own server, or from a source which allows cross-origin use of the images/videos. See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image

Comment: @Teemu Thank you. This is the way it is now. The question is Error only on Android, ios and desktop web are ok.

Comment: When I play MP4, it works, but when I play m3u8(hls), I get this error